# Create ranges from an array of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++14

> Given an array of `int`s, return a string identifying the range of
>   numbers.
>
> Example:
>
> - Input arr - [0 1 2 7 21 22 1098 1099]
> - Output - "0-2,7,21-22,1098-1099"

Is there any improvement possible in this implementation?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<sstream>

std::string  range_creator(std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(vec),std::end(vec));

    int first=vec.at(0);
    int prev=first-1;

    std::stringbuf buffer;
    std::ostream os (&buffer);

    for(auto &x : vec)
    {
       if(++prev == x)
           continue;
        else
        {

           if(first != --prev)
           {               
               os << first<<"-"<<prev<<",";
               prev=x;
               first=x;
           }
           else
           {
               os<<first<<",";
               prev=x;
               first=x;
           }


        }

    }
    if(first != prev)
    {
        os<<first<<"-"<<prev;
    }
    else
    {  
       os<<first; 
    }
    return buffer.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec={0,1,2,7,8,9,10,21,22,23,24,25,27,1098,1099,1100,2000};
    std::cout<<range_creator(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make good use of [`std::adjacent_find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/). Like this:

```
std::string range_creator(std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    auto first = std::begin(vec), last = std::end(vec);
    if(first == last)
        return "";
    std::sort(first, last);
    std::stringbuf buffer;
    std::ostream os (&buffer);
    while(true)
    {
        auto mid = std::adjacent_find(first, last,
                [](int x, int y){ return x + 1 != y; });
        if(mid == last)
            break;
        if(first == mid)
            os << *first << ",";
        else
            os << *first << "-" << *mid << ",";
        first = ++mid;
    }
    if(first == --last)
        os << *first;
    else
        os << *first << "-" << *last;
    return buffer.str();
}
```

I think my code is still subject to further improvements, but I'm no expert, so I'll leave it to the community.

Comment: I don't like `while(true)` loops; I'd declare `mid` at function scope and initialize it both just before the loop, then at the very end of the loop, and have `(mid != last)` be the condition.

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- You better not mix data processing with printing in algorithms, that's [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). So I divided your code into two parts.
- Fixed multiple occurrences of numbers.
- I used the iterator directly rather than accessing `.at(0)` before the loop. Your code segfaults when given an empty vector.
- I used [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead of `std::stringbuf` and `std::ostream`.

---

I hope all situations are handled properly. Here is the code, self-contained, compilable and lightly tested:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<sstream>

void getRangesFromList(std::vector<int> &list, std::map<int, int> &ranges)
{
    int min = -1, max = -1;
    std::sort(std::begin(list),std::end(list));
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it;
    for (it=list.begin(); it!=list.end();++it) {
        if (max == -1) {
            max = *it;
            min = *it;
            continue;
        }
        if (*it == max+1) {//growing in our range
            max = *it;
            continue;
        } else { //finish range and reset
            ranges[min] = max;
            min = *it;
            max = *it;
        }
    }
    if (list.size())
        ranges[min] = max;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = {0,1,2,7,7,7,8,9,10,21,22,23,24,25,27,1098,1099,1100,2000};
    std::map<int, int> ranges;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator rr;
    std::ostringstream out;

    getRangesFromList(nums, ranges);
    std::cout << "Got ranges of size " << ranges.size() << std::endl;
    for(rr=ranges.begin(); rr != ranges.end(); ++rr) {
        if (rr != ranges.begin())
            out << ",";
        out << rr->first;
        if (rr->first != rr->second)
            out << "-" << rr->second;
    }
    std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Got ranges of size 6
0-2,7-10,21-25,27,1098-1100,2000
```